# При выполнении execCommand не добавляется тег span с помощью команды insertHTML

Tags: javascript

```js
const getFirstTemplate = ()=>`<span>[ДОБАВЛЕНО]</span>`;
const element = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"');

element.addEventListener('mouseup', event=>{
  document.execCommand('insertHTML',false, getFirstTemplate());
  
});
element.addEventListener('input', event=>{
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">кликнуть-по-тексту</div>
```

Почему не добавляется `span`, и почему появляется `<br>`? Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

Как оказалось, это ожидаемое поведение,ведь сам тег `span` не несет никакой смысловой нагрузки и умный браузер его просто игнорирует. Но стоит добавить в тег описание, он начинает расцениваться, как необходимый.

```js
const getFirstTemplate = ()=>`<span class="text">[ДОБАВЛЕНО]</span>`;
const element = document.querySelector('[contenteditable="true"');

element.addEventListener('mouseup', event=>{
  document.execCommand('insertHTML',false, getFirstTemplate());
  
});
element.addEventListener('input', event=>{
  console.log(event.target.innerHTML);
});
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true">кликнуть-по-тексту</div>
```

На самом деле ответ можно считать и  верным и нет,так как он работает только при таком раскладе. Если изменить структуру дерева или изменить сами `html` теги, то работать уже не будет. Пишут что это какие-то баги и судя по датам устранять их не торопятся.

Эта особенность, к моему  разочарованию, делает `contenteditable` вообще не пригодным к использованию. Так как если создать собственную функцию добавления `html` в редактор, что не составит труда, обяжет писать самому систему `undo\redo` что является не таким простым и что обязывает писать редактор полностью самому.